# Google Spreadsheet Table into a single column with dropdown

Tags: google-sheets, dropdown, spreadsheet, rowheader

Please help me to sort this data in a single column with table headers as drop downs and when selecting the drop down menu appropriate data should be loaded below that header.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuAPm.jpg)

Comment: Post data as text table so that we can copy or share a workbook. Also show what output you desire.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Also consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few ways to do that. You can try `INDEX()/MATCH()` formula.

```
=INDEX(A3:C5,,MATCH(G2,A2:C2,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for help, If we need fetch data from another spreadsheet for the same result. Please help  I googled a lot but no luck.

Comment: Then you have to use `IMPORTRANGE()` function.